# Is there an iPhone API that allows me to use VoiceOver directly in my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, accessibility, accessibility-api

I'd like to allow a user to press a button directly from my app and read what's on the screen using VoiceOver. Right now, my only option is bundling recordings of each page and just playing them when the user presses the button. VoiceOver would really simplify this process. Is it possible?

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: Not sure. I must have hit it by mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for more info on someone who wanted to do something similar see [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130218100340/http://www.mobileorchard.com/programming-the-iphone-for-accessibility-by-the-visually-impaired/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this

```
if (UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()) {
   UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification,
                                   @"Result has been computed.");
}
```

For further API details...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I came up against something similar.. to avoid recording a massive pile of audio ... you can use non native Text To Speech like the Flite Engine (which is free).  Unfortunately the native Voice Over remains private - and also hijacks the touches you would hope to use for button presses!

https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts